# bootstrap 4 table search not returning good rows

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have a table with bootstrap 4 but when you search I get this:
[image]

As you can see I search for data but for some reason also HDMI > HDMI for example pops up which has no word of data in it.

Why is that and how can I solve this?

Here is my code for the table:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<?php
include("protected.php");
?>
<title>Inventory</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Dashboard</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
</head>

    <script src="ddtf.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        .glyphicon {
    font-size: 20px;
}
        .wrapper{
            width: auto;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        .page-header h2{
            margin-top: 0;
        }
        table tr td:last-child a{
            margin-right: 15px;
        }

        .red {
            background-color: #f44336 !important;
        }

        .oranje {
            background-color: #FFC107 !important;
        }
        .test{
            display: inline;
        }
        
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();   
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<?php include_once("navbar.html"); ?>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="page-header clearfix">
                        <h2 class="pull-left">Inventaris</h2>
                        <!-- <a href="create.php" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Voeg product toe</a> -->
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    // Include config file
                    require_once "config.php";
                    // Attempt select query execution
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY merk,model";
                    if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
                        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                            echo "<table id='dtBasicExample' class='table table-bordered table-striped '>";
                                echo "<thead>";
                                    echo "<tr>";
                                        echo "<th>Merk</th>";
                                        echo "<th>Model</th>";
                                        echo "<th>voorraad</th>";
                                        echo "<th>threshold</th>";
                                        echo "<th>Action</th>";
                                    echo "</tr>";
                                echo "</thead>";
                                echo "<tbody>";
                                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                                    $sql2 = "SELECT SUM(aantal) FROM mutaties WHERE product_id = ".$row['id'];
                                    if($result2 = mysqli_query($link, $sql2)){
                                    $row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2);
                                        if(empty($row2['SUM(aantal)'])){
                                            $voorraad = "0";
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            $voorraad = $row2['SUM(aantal)'];
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        echo "Error";
                                    }
                                        
                                    if($voorraad < $row['threshold']) 
                                    {
                                        $sql4 = "SELECT * FROM orders WHERE geleverd = 0 AND product_id =" .$row['id'];
                                        if($result4 = mysqli_query($link,$sql4))
                                        {
                                                if(mysqli_num_rows($result4)>0)
                                                {
                                                    $classNaam = 'oranje';
                                                }
                                                else
                                                {
                                                    $classNaam = 'red';
                                                }
                                        }

                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        $classNaam = '';
                                        
                                    }


                                    echo '<tr class="' . $classNaam . '">';
                                        echo "<td>" . $row['merk'] . "</td>";
                                        echo "<td>" . $row['model'] . "</td>";
                                        echo "<td>" . $voorraad . "</td>";
                                        echo "<td>" . $row['threshold'] . "</td>";
                                        echo "<td >";
                                            echo "<a onclick='return window.confirm(\"Weet je zeker dat je ".$row['merk']." ".$row['model']." wilt verwijderen?\")' href='delete.php?id=". $row['id'] ."' title='Delete Record' data-toggle='tooltip'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash' style='color:black'></span></a>";
                                            echo "<a href='uitgaand_order.php?id=". $row['id'] ."' title='Uitgaand' data-toggle='tooltip'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-upload' style='color:black'></span></a>";
                                            echo "<a href='inkomend_order.php?id=". $row['id'] ."' title='Inkomend' data-toggle='tooltip'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-download' style='color:black'></span></a>";
                                            echo "<a href='inkomend_uitgaand_pp.php?id=". $row['id'] . "&in=".TRUE. "&uit=".TRUE."' title='Inkomend/Uitgaand' data-toggle='tooltip'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-sort' style='color:black'></span></a>";
                                            echo "<a href='update_product.php?id=". $row['id'] ."' title='Inkomend' data-toggle='tooltip'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-pencil' style='color:black'></span></a>";
                                            echo "</td>";
                                    echo "</tr>";
                                }
                                echo "</tbody>";                            
                            echo "</table>";
                            // Free result set
                            mysqli_free_result($result);
                        } else{
                            echo "<p class='lead'><em>Er zijn momenteel geen producten</em></p>";
                        }
                    } 
                    else{
                    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
                    }
                    // Close connection
                    mysqli_close($link);
                    ?>
                </div>
                <script>
                $('#dtBasicExample').dataTable( {
  "pageLength": 100
} );
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#dtBasicExample').DataTable();
} );
            </script>
            </div>        
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I type in the search field HDMI all the hdmi show up and nothing more.

Comment: This is not because of `bootstrap 4`. Check your search query'

Comment: I dont have a search query this a the whole script for my inventory page that shows up in the picture

Comment: are you using a framework

Comment: no I dont use a framework

Comment: Someone that can help me?

Comment: come into chat room

Comment: @NipunTharuksha wich one?